# JS function missing an output after first input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a tool that will compare two basketball teams' statistics, with an HTML dropdown menu interface & a JS script. The script is supposed to (as of now,) read in the 2 selected teams from the input upon clicking the "submit" button, replace an input with a different value (if it has spaces in the input), and output them to the console.

After I refresh the page, Select the two teams, and click "submit," I receive both teams' names in the console. HOWEVER, if I try to select two different teams again (without refreshing the page), I will only see the console return the second team.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Analytics Comparator</title>
    </head>
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <body>
        <h1>Analytics Tool</h1>
        <p>Select the teams you want to compare and you will receive side-by-side data for each one!</p>
        <div class="teams-dropdown">
            <form name="selectTeam" id="selectTeam" action="/script">
                Team A: <select name="teamA" id="teamA">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Team</option>
                    </select>
                Team B: <select name="teamB" id="teamB">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"> Select a Team</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getNames();">
            </form>
        </div>
        <br></br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, here is my JS:

```
const Teams = [
"Akron",
"Miami",
"Michigan State",
"Norfolk State",
"Yale",
"North Carolina"
];

window.onload = function() {
  var teamSelA = document.getElementById("teamA");
  var teamSelB = document.getElementById("teamB");
  for (var x in Teams) {
    teamSelA.options[teamA.options.length] = new Option(Teams[x]);
    teamSelB.options[teamB.options.length] = new Option(Teams[x]);
  }
};
function alter_spaces(x){
  var y;
  switch (x) {
    case Teams[2]:
      y = "Michigan_State";
      break;
    case Teams[3]:
        y = "Norfolk_State";
        break;
    case Teams[5]:
        y = "North_Carolina";
        break;
    default: y = x;
  }
  return y;
};

function getNames(){
 t_a = document.getElementById("teamA").value; 
 t_b = document.getElementById("teamB").value;

 t_a = alter_spaces(t_a);
 t_b = alter_spaces(t_b);

 console.log(t_b);
 console.log(t_a);
};
```

Here is how the dropdown looks:
[image: Dropdown layout]

Here is my output after the first time submitting (post-refresh, "Akron" and "Michigan State" selected):

[image: first console output]

Here is my output, if I select "Yale" and "Norfolk State" and submit (no refresh in-between):

[image: console output of second form submission]

I have tried separating the team A and team B inputs into separate functions to no avail. I have also tried only selecting names that need to go through `alter_spaces` to see if there was an issue there, to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this problem, but (unfortunately) in my case it works fine. Could you check this demo and tell me what I did wrong? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b7cyxpg4/

Comment: @DominikChudy This code did produce a successful result! When compared with my code, you did not use a `<form>`  tag inside of the `<div>` that enclosed the dropdowns, simply writing both options directly in the `<div>`. When I took out the `<form>`, the code worked as intended! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help!